# do NestJs or TypeScript provide premade exceptions like 'KeyNotFoundException'

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I would like to create a NestJs backend and started with some REST endpoints but would like to support GraphQL later on too.

Let's assume I want to delete a user by id. The service layer knows if that user was deleted by checking the amount of deleted rows. If it's not zero, the user was deleted. If it's zero I want to throw a "Not found exception".

I know that Nest ships with some premade http exceptions https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#built-in-http-exceptions. But I don't want to use those exceptions in my service layer because I think they should only be used in the HTTP layer (REST controllers).

So I created my own exceptions

```
export class KeyNotFoundException extends Error {
  constructor(message: string) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

and use them in my service layer and maybe repository layer too.

```
public async deleteUserById(id: number): Promise<void> {
  const deletedRows: number = await this.usersRepository.deleteUserById(id);

  if (deletedRows === 0) {
    // my custom exception
    throw new KeyNotFoundException(`User with Id ${id} not found`);
  }
}
```

The controller could deal with this exception and throw a 404 or 500 if the error is not a `KeyNotFoundException`

```
@Delete(':id')
public async deleteUserById(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): Promise<void> {
  try {
    await this.usersService.deleteUserById(id);
  } catch (error) {
    // my custom Exception
    if (error instanceof KeyNotFoundException) {
      // premade NestJs exception will throw 404
      throw new NotFoundException(error.message);
    }

    // premade NestJs exception will throw 500
    throw new InternalServerErrorException();
  }
}
```

I am not satisfied with the solution because I have translate my custom exceptions to NestJs HTTP exceptions all the time. And maybe the service could come up with multiple exceptions, I would have to use a switch to check for the correct exception type.

Are there any better ideas on how to solve this?

C# for example comes with a [KeyNotFoundException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception?view=netframework-4.8) but I think for TypeScript I have to create my own exception system.

Comment: Have a look at `Exception filters` https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters . You could have a global exception filter by using `app.useGlobalFilters()` to map all your exceptions at the same place, but I would recommend to separate them based on you controller.

Comment: thanks, I read about this https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1 and see they deal with HttpExceptions and return a custom response to the client. So I should create multiple filters to map those exceptions and return the matching HttpException?

Comment: In a filter, you could catch all the exceptions that exit your controller and map them to the correct http code. The annotation `@Catch()` can take multiple exception. But if you want to be more specific, you can create filters for every entry point of your controller. I got here an example where I catch my own exception if that can help you : https://github.com/GabLeg/nestjs-example/blob/master/src/controllers/exceptions/exception-filters/chuck-controller.exception-filter.ts

Comment: Hm yeah, you are using the `if (error instanceof ...)` too :) I think I could use global filters and then create one exception filter per custom exception right? Like `@Catch(KeyNotFoundException)` would return the NestJs `NotFoundException`

Comment: Yes you can have the global filter and specific filters at the same time. Also, I just looked up and you can add multiple filters in `UseFilters()`, so you could have a filter for every custom exception, but I never tried it. And yes `@Catch(KeyNotFoundException)` would be the way :)

Comment: if you would like to, you could answer this question :)

Comment: ah wait, do you think I really have to use the Express way? I'm looking for something like this but the `catch` function seems to force `void` as a return value. Example:  https://pastebin.com/KHGfjM1y

Comment: I think the solution for what you want to accomplish is to throw the exception and let the global filter make the mapping with the Http code. But I think the best is to let the `KeyNotFoundExceptionFilter` return the `response` with the appropriate http code. See the global filter like the ultimate final barrier to don't send crap to your consumers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, I think your current solution is completely valid. If you don't want to throw http exception from the service and throw a NotFound in the controller, there is no way around converting the two. To make it easy, you can create a generic exception factory which knows how to translate your service exceptions to an http exception. You can also take care of it as part of the middleware and not worry about it on the controller side

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. would you mind describing your solution a little bit more? The generic factory would act as a mapper? And what do you mean with the middleware, I thought this only runs before the controller request comes in. Same for NestJs pipes? So do you have a transformation in mind? :)

Comment: I'm highly interested in your generic factory approach because I would still need a Hashmap or something to map it right?

Comment: it looks like you have a good suggestion on built-in NestJs solution... in general, I would create a map of `ExceptionType --> HttpExceptionType`, then for each exception caught, I would check if it exists in the keys, if so I would get the related `HttpExceptionType` and instantiate it with the caught exception as an inner exception